# ViewDoesNotExist at /savetester/ Could not import community.views. Error was: cannot import name models

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error while trying to make a simple page that saves an e-mail into the db. Any help would be super appreciated! Thanks!

This is my models.py:

```
from django import forms
from django import models

class Tester(models.Model):
    email = models.TextField()

class TesterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tester
fields = ['testeremail']
```

And my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from community.models import Tester
def savetester(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        testeremail = request.POST.get('testeremail', '')
        tester_obj = Tester(email=testermail)
        tester_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/board/')
```

And my urls.py:

```
(r'^test/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = "test.html")),
(r'^savetester/$', 'community.views.savetester'),
```

And now my test.html:

```
<form action="/savetester/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">{% csrf_token %}
<label for="testeremail">E-Mail:</label><input type="text" name="testeremail" value="" id="testeremail" />
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add"></p>
</form>
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/savetester/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'sphene.community',
 'sphene.sphboard',
 'sphene.sphwiki',
 'sphene.sphblog']
Installed Middleware:
('sphene.community.middleware.ThreadLocals',
 'sphene.community.middleware.GroupMiddleware',
 'sphene.community.middleware.MultiHostMiddleware',
 'sphene.community.middleware.LastModified',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
 'sphene.community.middleware.PermissionDeniedMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  158.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  167.             raise ViewDoesNotExist("Could not import %s. Error was: %s" % (mod_name, str(e)))

Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /savetester/
Exception Value: Could not import community.views. Error was: cannot import name models
```

Comment: Style note: the standard convention is now "email" or at the start of sentences "Email"; while "e-mail" and "E-mail" still occur a fair bit, they're not the normal way it's written, and "E-Mail" is not the normal style at all.

Comment: Please trim down your question and don't just dump everything you have.

Answer (score 1):

`models` lives in `django.db`

`from django.db import models`

Comment: Well now I feel silly... thanks! Unfortunately now I get this error:

DatabaseError at /savetester/

relation "community_tester" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "community_tester" ("email") VALUES ('Hello@worl...